# Error in new Scanner

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I have a problem in my programm, I want the user of my programm to write the file he wants to use and then with loops, depending on the word he typed, a file will be used. Butmy programm never enters in one loop and I don't know where the problem comes from.

Here is my code:

```
        System.out.println("Nom du test case à lancer ? : ");
    Scanner saisieUtilisateur = new Scanner(System.in); 
    //on rentre l'adresse du fichier texte :
    String str = saisieUtilisateur.next();
    System.out.println(str);
    //Integer val = saisieUtilisateur.nextInt();
    //System.out.println(val);
    String chaine = "";
    String File="";
    int i=1;

    //Choix du fichier a prendre en compte suivant le choix de l'utilisateur
    if (str == "hello"){
        File = "C:\\exempleANT\\helloWordTexte.txt";
        System.out.println("dans la boucle 1");
    }
    else if(str == "bye"){
        System.out.println("dans la boucle 2");
        File =  "C:\\exempleANT\\FichiersTestExempleHelloWord\\bye.txt";
    }
    else if(str == "fake"){
        System.out.println("dans la boucle 3");
        File =  "C:\\exempleANT\\FichiersTestExempleHelloWord\\helloWordTexteFake.txt";
    }
    else  {
        System.out.println("ErreurTexte!");
        System.out.println("dans la boucle 4");

    }
```

And here is the result in the console when I run the programm and I type hello.

```
hello
hello
ErreurTexte!
dans la boucle 4
```

Comment: `Butmy programm never enters in one loop` . Where is `loop` in your program?
I'm sure that you meant conditional statement by that.

Comment: hint to think about: you are using reference comparison for the strings

Comment: There is no any loop.. But try to use .equals() method as said above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use .equals for string equality rather than '=='.

```
 if (str.equals("hello")){
     ...
 }
```

See - [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Yes sure, but I have to wait 8 minutes until I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JAVA 7 than it will be done simple way

```
//str is your String to get match with
    switch (str) {
    case "hello":
        File = "C:\\exempleANT\\helloWordTexte.txt";
        System.out.println("dans la boucle 1");
        break;
    case "bye":
        System.out.println("dans la boucle 2");
    File = "C:\\exempleANT\\FichiersTestExempleHelloWord\\bye.txt";
        break;
    case "fake":
        System.out.println("dans la boucle 3");
        File="C:\\exempleANT\\FichiersTestExempleHelloWord\\helloWordTexteFake.txt";
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("ErreurTexte!");
    System.out.println("dans la boucle 4");
    }
```

or you can use

```
 if (str.equals("hello")){
 ...// old way 
 }
```

Comment: @Anatch ur welcome buddy if considered as solution than accept it buddy I suggest to use Switch case instead of If/else as its more efficient if ur using java 7

Comment: I am not using JAVA 7 so it is only the old way that works, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if (str.equals("hello"))
    {
        File = "C:\\exempleANT\\helloWordTexte.txt";
        System.out.println("dans la boucle 1");
    }
```